# Not able to connect between Celery and Minio containers?

Tags: django, docker, celery, minio

In my Django app, I'm offloading resizing of uploaded videos to a celery worker. I'm also storing all media files in Minio S3 buckets.

The resizing goes well without any errors, however Celery can't connect to the Minio container. This is the logs from Celery:

```bash
celery-worker_1  | [2023-07-19 20:51:46,076: INFO/MainProcess] Task common.tasks.resize_video[c38a90eb-793e-4190-a681-94b69eafadc8] received
celery-worker_1  | ffmpeg version 4.3.6-0+deb11u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
celery-worker_1  |   built with gcc 10 (Debian 10.2.1-6)
celery-worker_1  | ffmpeg version 4.3.6-0+deb11u1[tcp @ 0x55c7500727c0]  Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers Connection to tcp://localhost:9000 failed: Cannot assign requested address
celery-worker_1  | http://localhost:9000/event_media/test_video.mp4: Cannot assign requested address
```

Question is: how do I make the Celery container to connect to `http://minio:9000/` rather than to localhost?

---

This is the docker-compose.yml file I'm using:

```yaml
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:14"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/myapp
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis:6
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  minio:
    image: minio/minio
    command: minio server /export
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - MINIO_ACCESS_KEY=dev_access
      - MINIO_SECRET_KEY=dev_secret

  celery-worker:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.celery
    env_file:
      - ./docker.dev.env
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    command: celery -A myapp worker --loglevel INFO
```

This is contents of the `docker.dev.env` file:

```ini
MINIO_STORAGE_ENDPOINT=minio:9000
MINIO_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY=dev_access
MINIO_STORAGE_SECRET_KEY=dev_secret
MINIO_STORAGE_USE_HTTPS=False
MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME=media-dev
MINIO_STORAGE_AUTO_CREATE_MEDIA_BUCKET=True
MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_URL=http://localhost:9000/
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE=minio_storage.storage.MinioMediaStorage
```

Edit: Tried to change

```ini
MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_URL=http://minio:9000/
```

Which instead gave me this following error:

```bash
celery-worker_1  | [http @ 0x55698dd429c0] HTTP error 403 Forbidden
celery-worker_1  | http://minio:9000/event_media/test_video.mp4: Server returned 403 Forbidden (access denied)
```

Still scratching my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pouring over the documentation at https://django-minio-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#django-settings-configuration, and specifically the setting key `MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_URL`, I updated `docker.dev.env`:

From

```ini
MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_URL=http://localhost:9000/
```

To

```ini
MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_URL=http://minio:9000/media-dev
```

What I learned was:

1. that `localhost` points on its own container, thus need to use the container name `minio` instead (as defined in `docker-compose.yml`).
2. The `MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_URL` should *also* contain the name of the minio bucket, in this case "media-dev" as defined by `MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME`.